# openpyxl скорость чтения из ячеек Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, openpyxl

Есть код программы. Работает отлично все считает и все такое, Но, работает очень медленно, а также при натыкании на пустую ячейку не выполняет брейк, а продолжает считывать их и вследствие чего в список попадают None ячейки.
Есть ли возможность увеличить скорость считывания, и решить проблему с попаданием None ячеек в список?

```
wb = load_workbook(filename='test2.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['ws1']
i = 0
data = ([ws.cell(row=i,column=4).value for i in range(2,3156)])
for x in data:
    if x == None:
        break
    else: data[i] = datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S")
    i += 1
print(data)
```

Comment: Скорость - это проблема всех библиотек для xlsx(xlsxwriter, xlwt не исключение)-http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_memory.html - там жесть какая-то, 30 секунд на несчастные 10000 строк, хотя концептуально это вроде чтение/запись в XML файл, не знаю, что там может быть такого долгого. Также пустоту ячейки вы можете проверить ее длиной - есть в ячейке ничего нет, то длина ее содержимого == 0.`None`-означает ничего, буквально ничего. Если ячейка `is None`, то ее нет.Она на самом деле есть, но пуста - используйте `if not len(x): break` для проверки на пустоту (отсутствие данных внутри)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [read_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) из модуля [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/test2.xlsx', usecols=[4], header=None, skiprows=2)
data = pd.to_datetime(data, errors='coerce').tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. По поводу скорости - чтение/запись в загруженную книгу осуществляется как в обычные переменные, т.к. они располагаются в оперативной памяти, но чтение/запись в файл происходит медленно, вероятно из-за кодирования/декодирования в формат excel.
2. Я бы заменил `range(2 ,3156)` на `range(1, 1+len(ws['A0']))`, так цикл пройдет по всем существующим рядам в таблице.
3. Я не знаю, почему `x == None` у вас не работает. Можно попробовать преобразовать `x` - `bool(x)`, тогда если `x` будет ничем (например `0`, `None`, `''`, `[]`), то `bool(x)` будет `False` => `if not bool(x): break`